# Square v1 API for adding card to customer(New/Existing)

Tags: square-connect

There is a Square v2 endpoint to create a card for a customer as described in the link, https://developer.squareup.com/docs/api/connect/v2#endpoint-customers-createcustomercard

I will not be able to use the same API for applications in v1 version. I tried and faced the below error,

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "category": "INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR",
        "code": "V1_APPLICATION",
        "detail": "This application does not support accessing Connect API v2 endpoints. To access these endpoints, register a new application with Square at connect.squareup.com."
    }]
}
```

If I need to add a card to a customer like the one mentioned for v2 API, which endpoint of v1 should I rely on?

Answer (score 0):

There are no endpoints in V1 that allow adding a card to a customer's profile. This functionality only exists in V2. If you are receiving that error, then unfortunately, your application was created before V2, and the only way to use V2 endpoints would be to create a new application (which just means updating your access token and secrets appropriately).